# Is there a correspondence between Antahkarana and Chaturvyuha?

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism, consciousness

The Antahkarana (Inner Organ or Inner Cause) is composed of four parts:

- Chitta (Consciousness)
- Manas (Mind)
- Ahamkara (Ego)
- Buddhi (Intellect)

The Chaturvyuhas are the primitive emanations of Sriman Narayana and are listed as follows:

- Vasudeva
- Sankarshana
- Pradyumna
- Aniruddha

Is there a one-one correspondence between the two lists? If so, what does this relationship indicate?